# How to handle empty array inside transform() in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a nested dataframe, where I am trying to update a certain element within a struct of a array. I am able to achieve that using F.transform(). However the problem arises, when the array within the struct is empty, then getting syntax error :

```
\[INVALID_EXTRACT_BASE_FIELD_TYPE\] Can't extract a value from "namedlambdavariable()". Need a complex type \[STRUCT, ARRAY, MAP\] but got "STRING".
```

I have a dataframe in pyspark where the nested structure is as follows:

```
\`|-- details: array (nullable = true)

|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

|    |    |-- lineempid: array (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

|    |    |    |    |-- empidname: string (nullable = true)\`
```

My objective is to update the value of empidname. I am using the following syntax, which is working as expected

```
df.withColumn(
    "details",
    F.transform(
        "details",
        lambda x: x.withField( 
            "lineempid", 
            F.transform(                
                x.lineempid,
                lambda y: y.withField("empidname", when(F.lower(y.empidname) == "tom","Tom").when(F.lower(y.empidname) == "roy",    "Roy").when(F.lower(y.empidname) == "greg",    "Greg").otherwise(F.lit(y.empidname)))))))
```

As empidname is of NULL types sometimes in dataframe, value of empidname is NOT populating, so in that case dataframe is populating as follows:

```
\`|-- details: array (nullable = true)

|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

|    |    |-- lineempid: array (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)\`
```

In this schema, the above code base is failing.

I am getting the below error :

```
\[INVALID_EXTRACT_BASE_FIELD_TYPE\] Can't extract a value from "namedlambdavariable()". Need a complex type \[STRUCT, ARRAY, MAP\] but got "STRING".
```

Any leads will be really appreciated.

TIA